# Python load array from ascii-styled .txt file

Tags: python, arrays

There's a .txt file called "array.txt" which contains the following 5x5 array of two digit numbers:

```
+-------------------------+

¦ 34 ¦ 21 ¦ 32 ¦ 41 ¦ 25  ¦

+----+----+----+----+-----¦

¦ 14 ¦ 42 ¦ 43 ¦ 14 ¦ 31  ¦

+----+----+----+----+-----¦

¦ 54 ¦ 45 ¦ 52 ¦ 42 ¦ 23  ¦

+----+----+----+----+-----¦

¦ 33 ¦ 15 ¦ 51 ¦ 31 ¦ 35  ¦

+----+----+----+----+-----¦

¦ 21 ¦ 52 ¦ 33 ¦ 13 ¦ 23  ¦

+-------------------------+
```

I want a script which reads this file automatically, without having to manually code:

```
array = np.matrix([[34,21,32,41,25],[14,42,43,14,31],[54,45,52,42,23],[33,15,51,31,35],[21,52,33,13,23]])
```

All I have is the following:

```
import numpy as np
np.loadtxt('array.txt', skiprows=1)
```

which returns the error "ValueError: could not convert string to float: b'xa6'". So it seems as if it doesn't like the ascii characters. Is there any function that can read only the numerical values of a text file into an array? Thanks a lot for reading, any help would be infinitely appreciated.

Comment: [Reading array from ascii-styled text file in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31030510/reading-array-from-ascii-styled-text-file-in-python)

Comment: @vaultah we under 10kers can't see that post.

Comment: @vaultah i thought this question looked familiar...

Comment: @River http://imgur.com/pA73vCS

Comment: is that exactly what the text file looks like with all of the dashes and what not? it would be in your convince to change that.

Comment: Yes I originally deleted it because I got the formatting wrong.

Comment: @Grassy and why are you under a different username?

Comment: @DaPounder Yes that's exactly it. Unfortunately I can't. Is there any way around this?

Comment: @heinst I started a new account because it's a fairly urgent problem and the site imposed a 90 minute waiting time before I could post again, but starting a new account couldn't get around this.

Comment: @vaultah As you can see I'm a complete beginner. I deleted it because I didn't want people reading it while I worked out the formatting.

Comment: Please avoid deleting questions if the formatting is the only problem. More experienced users are likely to fix the formatting issues within the first few minutes.

Comment: Note that \xa6 is _not ASCII_. Your file isn't ASCII.

Comment: @Grassy take a look at my answer. Remco is correct your file is not ascii its utf-8 so your python script need `# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-` at the top of it to not use `\xa6` in your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use regex to extract the numbers from the lines:

```
import re, numpy
with open(myFile, 'r') as content:
    # This extracts all word boundary-delimited numbers from each line
    x = [re.findall(r'\b\d+\b', i) for i in content.readlines()]
# Then you keep only those lines that contained a number and 
#  convert the resulting list to an array
myArray = numpy.array([i for i in x if len(i) > 0])
```

Comment: This works perfectly, thanks a lot! Don't know how you guys do this, you're all very talented.

Comment: Good answer! I made my own because there are several aspects that could be improved: you can leave out the word boundaries, and you can check if the regexp matches anything while you are iterating. And also I wanted to see if I can do the same in less lines :)

Answer (score 1):

Here is how to do it in one line, or two:

```
import re

import numpy as np


numbers = re.compile(r'\d+')

np.array([map(int, numbers.findall(line)) 
          for line in open("array.txt", "r") 
          if numbers.search(line) is not None])
```

Answer (score -1):

Assuming those are the only separators you'll ever run into in your .txt file, here's a little something that works in Python 2.7 as far as I know.

```
array = []
for line in open('array.txt', 'r').readlines():
    if line.startswith('\xc2'):
        line = line.replace('\xa6','').replace('\xc2',',').split(',')
        line[:] = [int(x) for x in line if x not in ['','\n']]
        array.append(line)
```

Calling an additional `print array` on the sample text file you gave yields this output:

```
[[34, 21, 32, 41, 25], [14, 42, 43, 14, 31], [54, 45, 52, 42, 23], [33,  15, 51, 31, 35], [21, 52, 33, 13, 23]]
```

From here you can adjust it to fit your numpy needs.

Comment: Thank you so much. However I've just tried this and when I append print(array) it just returns []. Is there something I've missed?

Comment: I get a null output also.

Comment: Can you post the relevant code in a gist? I can't say for certain what's going on without actually looking at what you've got, but if you're using Python 3, the behavior of `print()` might be different.

Comment: This is the array file: http://textuploader.com/yoee. Perhaps I should have mentioned the spaces? Edit: yes I apologise, the spaces were the problem.